# Change function does not fire on change of dropdownlistFor in Razor view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have a dropdownListFor in Razor view and I would like Jquery change function to fire when value is changed.

Razor Code of Dropdown

```
 <li id="servicesOffer"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#services" hidden>Services Offered</a></li>

 <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerProfile.CustomerTypeId, "Customer Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

      <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerProfile.CustomerTypeId, Model.CustomerProfile.CustomerTypeList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control spCheck"})
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerProfile.CustomerType.CustomerTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
 </div>
```

Jquery Code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.spCheck').change(function () {
            if ($('.spCheck').val() == 1 || $('.spCheck').val() == 3) {
                $("servicesOffer").attr("hidden", false)
            }
            else {
                $("servicesOffer").attr("hidden", false)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would like change function to be called in my jquery so I have add the hidden attribute to a li.

Comment: Are you loading this dropdown control dynamically? I mean was it hidden first and then you're showing it on screen?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal No, it shows up when I load the screen. Do you want to see any code?

Comment: Try to use `$(document, '.spCheck').on( 'change', function(){`